# PHP 8 - merge transparent image over another one

Tags: php, php-8

I have two images:

`$imageBG` is the image which needs to be as background

`$stamp` is an image with the same dimensions and has text on it, the background of it is completely transparent.

I tried:

```
   imagecopy($imageBG, $stamp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $stampwidth, $stampheight);
   header('Content-Type: image/png');
   imagepng($imageBG);
```

It results in only `$stamp` being visible without the background `$imageBG`

then I tried:

```
imagealphablending($stamp, true);
imagesavealpha($stamp, true);
imagecopy($stamp, $imageBG, 0, 0, 0, 0, $stampwidth, $stampheight);
```

now only `$imageBG` is visible

I also tried couple other "solutions"

Maybe they are just outdated for PHP 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how to do this:

```
$final_img = imagecreatetruecolor($stampwidth, $stampheight);
imagealphablending($final_img, true);
imagesavealpha($final_img, true);
imagecopy($final_img, $imageBG, 0, 0, 0, 0, $stampwidth, $stampheight);
imagecopy($final_img, $stamp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $stampwidth, $stampheight);
```